Having issues coding a EM algorithm in R to a mixture poisson distribution to converge to the maximum values for p, lambda1, and lambda2
 # Function for the E step (Expected Value Part of the Algorithm) for Poisson Distribution
     E_step <- function(Y, lambda1, lambda2, p) {
 # Get the Poisson 1 distribution probability
    poisson1_prob <- dpois(Y, lambda1) * p
 # Get the Poisson 2 distribution probability
    poisson2_prob <- dpois(Y, lambda2) * (1 - p)
 # Add up the probabilities to get the total probability
    total_poisson_prob <- poisson1_prob + poisson2_prob
 # Get the expected value for the probability
    expected_value <- poisson1_prob / total_poisson_prob
 # Return the expected value
    return(expected_value)
  }

 # Function for the M step (Maximization Part of the Algorithm) for Poisson Distribution
   M_step <- function(X, expected_value) {
   # Update p
      p <- mean(expected_value)
   # Update Lambda 1
     lambda1 <- sum(expected_value * X) / sum(expected_value)
  # Update Lambda 2
     lambda2 <- sum((1 - expected_value) * X) / sum(1 - expected_value)
  # Returning a list of the updated p, lambda1, and lambda2
     return(list(p = p, lambda1 = lambda1, lambda2 = lambda2))
}

# Function to run through multiple iterations (do the EM algorithm multiple times)
  fullEM <- function(Y, X, lambda1_init, lambda2_init, p_init, num_iter) {
# Initialize parameters
     lambda1 <- lambda1_init
     lambda2 <- lambda2_init
     p <- p_init
# Initialize vectors to store parameter values for each iteration
     p_new <- numeric(num_iter)
     lambda1_new <- numeric(num_iter)
     lambda2_new <- numeric(num_iter)
     for (i in 1:num_iter) {
         # E-step
         expected_value <- E_step(Y, lambda1, lambda2, p)
         # M-step
         parameters_final <- M_step(X, expected_value)
         # Update parameters
         p <- parameters_final$p
         lambda1 <- parameters_final$lambda1
         lambda2 <- parameters_final$lambda2
      # Store updated parameter values
         p_new[i] <- p
         lambda1_new[i] <- lambda1
         lambda2_new[i] <- lambda2
       }
  # Return the updated parameters for each iteration
     return(list(p = p_new, lambda1 = lambda1_new, lambda2 = lambda2_new))
 }

Using this code, I want the code to actually maximize p, lambda1, and lamnda2, but it is oscillating between two numbers like this for all three of the returned variables, which makes me think there is a convergence issue.
# Example Usage with Fake Data
 Y <- c(200, 183, 210, 167, 143, 86, 33, 9, 5)
 X <- c(0:8)
 lambda1_init <- 3
 lambda2_init <- 2.3
 p_init <- 0.5
 num_iter <- 50
 result=fullEM(Y, X, lambda1_init, lambda2_init, p_init, num_iter)
 result

$p
 [1] 0.9440265 0.1717453 0.8895388 0.1363953 0.8756368 0.1297041 0.8727133 0.1283712 0.8721172
[10] 0.1281024 0.8719964 0.1280480 0.8719720 0.1280370 0.8719670 0.1280348 0.8719660 0.1280343
[19] 0.8719658 0.1280342 0.8719658 0.1280342 0.8719658 0.1280342 0.8719658 0.1280342 0.8719658
[28] 0.1280342 0.8719658 0.1280342 0.8719658 0.1280342 0.8719658 0.1280342 0.8719658 0.1280342
[37] 0.8719658 0.1280342 0.8719658 0.1280342 0.8719658 0.1280342 0.8719658 0.1280342 0.8719658
[46] 0.1280342 0.8719658 0.1280342 0.8719658 0.1280342

$lambda1
 [1] 3.781219 7.621238 3.522136 7.747245 3.461137 7.773168 3.448297 7.778381 3.445677 7.779434
[11] 3.445146 7.779647 3.445039 7.779691 3.445017 7.779699 3.445012 7.779701 3.445012 7.779701
[21] 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702
[31] 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702
[41] 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702

$lambda2
 [1] 7.689878 3.249107 7.848216 3.408171 7.794115 3.437668 7.782632 3.443530 7.780295 3.444712
[11] 7.779822 3.444951 7.779726 3.444999 7.779706 3.445009 7.779703 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011
[21] 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011
[31] 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011
[41] 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011 7.779702 3.445011

I have tried increasing the number of iterations and changing around the values for lambda1 and lambda2, but nothing seems to helping.
